# pugixml parser getting element value

Tags: c++, pugixml

I have XML with structure like this:

```
 <info>
     <students>
         <student>
             <name>John</name>
             <street>
                 <name>abcdef</name>
                 <number>55</number>
             </street>
         </student>
     </students>  
  </info>
```

And I correctly print value of name tag with this code

```
pugi::xml_node students = doc.child("info").child("students");

for (pugi::xml_node student = students.child("name"); student; student= student.next_sibling("student"))
    {
        std::cout << "name '" << student.child_value("name") << "'\n";
    }
```

But, I also need to print values of name & number - tags inside street and I could not succeed.

Here is code to display values from that two tag elements:

```
pugi::xml_node student = doc.child("students").child("student");

for (pugi::xml_node street = student.child("street"); street; street = student.next_sibling("street"))
    {
        std::cout << "name '" << student.child_value("name") << "'\n";
        std::cout << "number '" << student.child_value("number") << "'\n";
    }
```

**but it  shows nothing.**

Anyone knows what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you still have `student` but it needs to be `street`

```
for (pugi::xml_node street = student.child("street"); street; street = street.next_sibling("street"))
{
    std::cout << "name '" << street.child_value("name") << "'\n";
    std::cout << "number '" << street.child_value("number") << "'\n";
}
```

<strike>If you compare my loop to the second one you posted in your question you will see that I have replaced `student` with `street` in several places. I guess you copy pasted your first loop but forgot to change those values.</strike>

I see you changed the code in your question - but it still needs to be `street = street.next_sibling('street')` to loop through all the streets for a particular student.

**Addition**

Just noticed - your code to get the `student` node is missing the `info` node

You have:

```
`pugi::xml_node student = doc.child("students").child("student");`
```

It should be:

```
`pugi::xml_node student = doc.child("info").child("students").child("student");`
```

Comment: @Junior try printing the value of the name directly to get the right syntax. Does `std::cout << doc.child('info').child('students').child('student).child('street').child_value('name');` work?